# Add a jQuery table from a simple .php to .blade.php Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a website with navigation bar (which is in main.blade.php). I have created a jQuery table but not in the blade view but as a simple .php. How can I set the content section to it and add it to the blade? Thanks!

Routes:

web.php

old(a simple page from the blade):

```
Route::get('/manageclasses', ['as' => 'manageclasses', 'uses' => 'UserView\AdminController@manageclasses']);
```

the new one(a simple page with table):

```
Route::get('/manageclasses',['as' => 'manageclasses',function(){
  $manageclasa = App\Elevi::all();
  return View::make('table')->with('manageclasa', $manageclasa);
}]);
```

My blade layout where I would like to add the table

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@extends('layouts.navbar')
@extends('layouts.sidebar')


@section('content')
<h3 class="white-text">Manage Page</h3>

@endsection
```

My new layout with the table

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Manage Clasa</title>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
   </head>


   <body>
      <h1>Elevi clasa</h1>
      <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Nume</th>
            <th>Prenume</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <?php foreach ($manageclasa as $elev): ?>
         <tr>
            <td><?php echo $elev['nume'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $elev['prenume'] ?></td>
         </tr>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
      </table>

      <script>
         $(function(){
            $("table").dataTable();
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the issue here?

Comment: I cannot add the table into the blade. I've tried in several methods but it was unsuccessful

Comment: so I need a sugestion how to make it

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an Eloquent Object. Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Manage Clasa</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>


<body>
<h1>Elevi clasa</h1>
<table id="elevi-clasa">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Nume</th>
  <th>Prenume</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($manageclasa as $elev)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $elev->nume }}</td>
  <td>{{ $elev->prenume }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(function(){
$("#elevi-clasa").dataTable();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would not need the original `<?php foreach ($manageclasa as $elev): ?>`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You're right. I have removed the extra foreach line.